# Using mingw32 glfw3 and glew32s binaries in cygwin32 without mixing cygwin X11 GLX with WGL

Tags: cygwin, linker-errors, glfw, glew

I want to use the cygwin32 compiler instead of mingw32. According to http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/glfw/ , the GLX programs of gl on cygwin don't work with glfw. So I tried to use mingw32 binaries of glfw3 in cygwin32, which gave errors like 'GL_ARRAY_BUFFER' was not declared in this scope. I solved that by linking with mingw32 binaries of glew32, which gave

/usr/include/w32api/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ')' before '*' token

which I solved two different ways, by instead using the glew installed by cygwin or by linking to glew32s and pasting

```
#ifndef CALLBACK
#if defined(_ARM_)
#define CALLBACK
#else
#define CALLBACK __stdcall
#endif
#endif

#define GLEW_STATIC
```

If I used glew32 instead of glew32s, it would say undefined reference to 'glewInit', which I need to stop the segfault right before the glCreateShader and after glfwMakeContextCurrent. But this method gave Warning: resolving _glewInit by linking to _glewInit@0.

After all that, I got a lot of errors like undefined reference to 'glGenTextures' or 'glDrawElements', which I could only solve by linking to cygwin's gl, which I think is mixing GLX with WGL.
According to
[glewInit() fails with "Missing GL version", SDL2 OpenGL context, cygwin compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297960/glewinit-fails-with-missing-gl-version-sdl2-opengl-context-cygwin-compiler) , I should just switch to mingw32 compiler, which I already have working, but I really want to use cygwin.

If I use cygwin's gl (-lGL) with glew32s, it compiles, runs, and segfaults with a stackdump at my glGenBuffers(1, &ibo); in my model class without glewinit() giving any errors.

```
model(vectx* vecticesd, unsigned int* indicesd,int vectsized,int indsized,GLuint texidd) :
vecticesarr(vecticesd), indicesarr(indicesd),texid(texidd),vectsize(vectsized),indsize(indsized){
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vectsized, vecticesarr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);                      //here it crashes
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indsized, indicesd, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

If I use cygwin's glew instead, the glewinit() returns the error "Missing GL version".
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); is called BEFORE glewinit();.
Here is my linkers and doubling them, so the orders don't matter, didn't change anything.

```
 -lglfw3 -lglew32s -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lGL
```

I tried mingw64 binaries with cygwin64 and it gave "___vsnprintf not found" and -lntdll didn't fix it.

--added more information--

I'm new to programming, so please forgive me if I say anything really dumb. For a test case, use the code at https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/quick.html . I get a black window with my cygwin32 build setup and the rotating triangle with my mingw32 build setup. I'm using sublime text on windows, if that matters. Can I use the pre-compiled binaries for mingw32 download from the glfw website, or do I have to use cmake with cygwin? When I tried cmake with cygwin by adding cygwin/bin to the environment system variable path, it said "Using Win32 for window creation", and both the cygwin/bin/make.exe and gnu windows make said

[ 16%] Linking C executable boing.exe
../src/glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'
... more errors

If I went into the cmakelist.txt in the glfw source and forced it to use X11, it said "Using X11 for window creation" and then make said X11/extensions/xf86vmode.h was missing and there wasn't a package for it in the setup-x86.exe thing for cygwin. I might of did something very wrong with the cmake, but I don't know. I was able to cmake, make, and make install with mingw32 as the native compiler in the environment system variable path.

Comment: Mixing cygwin and mingw is never a good idea. About the "don't work with glfw" you can check again or make a simple test and ask here or on the cygwin mailing list. For the rest please provide a STC (simple test case) otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I'm new to programming, so please forgive me if I say anything really dumb. For a test case, use the code at https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/quick.html . I get a black window with my cygwin32 setup and the rotating triangle with my mingw32 setup. I'm using sublime text on windows, if that matters. Can I use the pre-compiled binaries for mingw32 download from the glfw website, or do I have to use cmake with cygwin? I wrote some more in the question part above.

Comment: @matzeri: I forgot to put this notify thing in my reply.

Comment: I have a rotating colored triangle on cygwin 64 bit. How you built the glfw library for cygwin ?

Comment: @matzeri I couldn't figure out how to build it. I tried to use cmake with cygwin.

Comment: @matzeri I removed the cygwin/usr/include/GL/gl.h file and the test glfw code worked, but my original code still gives the same error. I think now it's linking to cygwin/usr/include/w32api/GL/gl.h by removing the other one.

Comment: Very bad idea. put it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using the wrong libraries so here is a step by step
on how to do it on Cygwin.
You need the to install of course cmake, make, libGL-devel, xinit and xwin-xdg-menu

**To run the Xserver and a X terminal**

[image]

It will shows two icons on the taskbar, go for the green X
and run Xterm.

[image]

**To compile:**
Download the source from
https://www.glfw.org/download.html

```
$ unzip glfw-3.2.1.zip
$ cd glfw-3.2.1
$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
$ make
$ make install
$ mv /usr/local/lib/cygglfw-3.dll /usr/local/bin/cygglfw-3.dll
```

the `mv` is needed as the proper place for shared lib on Cygwin is the `bin` directory
After that the example can be compiled with

```
$ gcc simple.c -o simple -lglfw -lgl  -L/usr/local/lib
```

and run in a Xterminal with

```
$ ./simple.exe
```

and this is a snapshot

[image: colored triangle]

To build all the samples:

```
$ cd examples
$ cmake .
$ make
```

and all are built at ones

```
$ ls *.exe
boing.exe  heightmap.exe  simple.exe     wave.exe
gears.exe  particles.exe  splitview.exe
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185479/discussion-on-answer-by-matzeri-using-mingw32-glfw3-and-glew32s-binaries-in-cygw).

Comment: Moderator-created rooms automatically grant access to all participants. See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/185479/?tab=access