# compile GLFW in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, glfw

I am trying to compile glfw with cygwin but getting errors like this

```
../src/glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
../src/glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x8a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_CreateDCW'
```

Can someone help here ? 
Anyone has successfull experience in compiling glfw with cygwin ?

Comment: Please clarify how you are installing the software as glfw3.lib is not for cygwin compilation. put all the steps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using mingw32 glfw3 and glew32s binaries in cygwin32 without mixing cygwin X11 GLX with WGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823318/using-mingw32-glfw3-and-glew32s-binaries-in-cygwin32-without-mixing-cygwin-x11-g)

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the libraries opengl32 and glfw3dll? Also have you included glad.h in your code? If so you should also include windows.h. Include the files in this order:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <path_to_glad/glad.h>
#include <path_to_glfw/glfw3.h>
```

Then compile the code like this:

```
gcc/g++ main.c glad.c -lglfw3dll -lopengl32
```

It would also be better if you included your code along with your question